# Unquoted hyphen in attribute selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I recently ran into a strange error where a selector stopped working after minification (using csswring 3.0.7). The selector in question matches elements where a data-property includes a hyphen. It worked in development but failed in production on all browsers tested (Chrome, Firefox, IE11, Edge).

After looking through the minified stylesheet, I found that the selector had been transformed from something like `[data-attr*="-"]` to `[data-attr*=-]`. Quotes have been removed and this is rejected by the browsers.

The thing is, I can't find any source that says a single hyphen requires quotes. Obviously the minifier-authors has found the same sources I have.

[This page](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values) details the relevant parts of the specification.

> So, a valid unquoted attribute value in CSS is any string of text that is not the empty string, consists of escaped characters and/or characters matching `/[-_\u00A0-\u10FFFF]/` entirely, and doesn’t start with a digit or two hyphens or a hyphen followed by a digit.

A single hyphen seems perfectly valid in this case.

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgram/064s493q/) testing different scenarios. Only when trying to match exactly a single, unquoted hyphen does the selector fail.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't this be a valid selector?

Comment: @Jonathan Lam: On rereading it, it seems to be a real problem. Apparently these selectors are being produced unquoted by a minifier. If they are quoted in the source and the quotes are being stripped by the minifier... it looks like the OP's only recourse is to get a new minifier.

Comment: Change the minifier. YUI compressor is the best that I test ever. http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/ || http://refresh-sf.com/ In the last URL (http://refresh-sf.com/ ) I test your line and it preserves the quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the precise text from the CSS2.1 specification itself as referenced by the article:

> In CSS, *identifiers* (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

As you can see, this does not appear to address the case regarding a single hyphen.

However, looking at the grammar in [section 4.1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#tokenization), we find the following tokenization for an ident:

```
[-]?{nmstart}{nmchar}*
```

`{nmstart}` is represented by `[_a-z]|{nonascii}|{escape}` and is mandatory in an ident. The preceding hyphen is optional, but as the hyphen does not appear in `{nmstart}`, this would imply that a single hyphen is not a valid CSS identifier.

Therefore, the selector `[data-attr*=-]` is indeed invalid, and a single hyphen has to be quoted in order to be treated as a string instead.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I’ve updated my write-up + tool (mentioned in OP’s question) accordingly. By the way, this also explains why the empty string is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @Mathias: Cool! Thanks for following up :)